# Is it normal to get mixed content warnings even if the HTTP request is redirected to HTTPS?

Tags: browser, https

I'm running Apache 2.4 and redirecting all HTTP requests to HTTPS.
And yet my browser will not display the green padlock in the URL bar, instead warning me of mixed content.
Taking a look at the browser console output, I can see that the browser does indeed make a request for some images via plain HTTP and gets redirected to HTTPS.

[image: Firefox console output]

So is it normal for those requests to set off the mixed content warning, even though the images are retrieved via HTTPS from the same domain? Happens on both Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Thats by design, if the browser issues a non-HTTP request it has no way to know there will be a redirect to HTTPS or that the redirect is legitimate.  All need to be served over HTTPS directly.

Comment: @AlexK. I guess that's reasonable. Thanks.